# Can do that array struct assign?

Tags: c, struct

I'm getting

```
error: expected expression before '{' token" at line 19 ( ( aluno[0].nota = {1, 2, 3}; ).
```

Any idea if can I do that array struct assign?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct CadAluno
{
    int matricula;
    char nome[100];
    float nota[3];
};

int main()
{
    struct CadAluno aluno[4];
    int i, j;
    float mediaAtual = 0, maiorMedia = 0;
    int vencedor;

    strcpy(aluno[0].nome, "Carlos");
    aluno[0].nota = {1, 2, 3};

    printf("Nota aluno[0].nome: %s\n", aluno[0].nome);
    printf("Nota aluno[0].nota[0]: %f\n", aluno[0].nota[0]);
}
```

Comment: Which language are you actually using: C or C++?

Comment: You cannot assign raw array like that in C or C++.

Comment: Even if you can make a "literal" array like `(float[]){1, 2, 3}`, you cannot assign an array to another array by a single assignment. You need to copy each element on its own.

Comment: Im using C laguange.

Comment: @RodrigoDias: Then please [edit] the question and remove the C++ tag. EDIT: Meanwhile, someone else has done it for you.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed, but you could instead use an initializer: `struct CadAluno aluno[4] = { { .nome = "Carlos", .nota = { 1, 2, 3 } } };`, which will initialize the values for `aluno[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

At least partly for historical reasons, an array cannot be used as a single object in C.

You can copy one array to another by using `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(aluna[0].nota, (float []) {1, 2, 3}, sizeof aluna[0].nota);
```

In this `(float []) {1, 2, 3}` is a *compound literal* that creates an array from which the bytes are copied. `sizeof aluna[0].nota` provides the number of bytes in the destination array. Be aware that works only when used on the array itself, not a pointer to the array.

You can also of course assign the members individually:

```
aluna[0].nota[0] = 1;
aluna[0].nota[1] = 2;
aluna[0].nota[2] = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't do that in C/C++ (traditionally). Though if you are using C++, you can use std::array and that lets you assign them, or if you want traditional arrays you can use std::copy. See the documentation for both.

Comment: Note that this question was originally tagged as both C and C++, but meanwhile OP has stated in the comments section that the question is about C, not C++. Due to this, the C++ tag has meanwhile been removed. This may have at least partially invalidated your answer, because you are mainly talking about C++ and not C.